# Two differently colored curves for CPU usage in Windows 10 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, performance-monitor

The windows 10 task manager suddenly shows two curves for CPU utilization, one light colored and one darker blue colored:
[image]

As far as I remember, it always used to show just one curve for current CPU utilization. What do the two curves mean? Which one should I trust to be correctly describing the resources spent on the current task?

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks for your reply, but what does that mean?

Comment: Use Right Click > Change Graph To > ...